APIM Policy example for extracting a specific item from a JSON array response
I have a JSON array response that returns values similar to:
[
    {
        "code": "SCH",
        "title": "School Email",
        "emailType": "school",
        "id": "123455"
    },
    {
        "code": "PER",
        "title": "Personal Email",
        "emailType": "personal",
        "id": "123456"
    }
]

In my APIM policy I want to match on an incoming code e.g. "PER" and store corresponding id result in the cache.
I've tried lots of variants of the following policy to extract a single value:
<set-variable name="emailId" 
value="@{var emailTypes = JArray.Parse(context.Variables["emailTypesList"].ToString());     
                    var emailId = emailTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x["code"].Value<string>() == "PER");                
                    return emailId?["id"]?.ToString();
                    }"/>

but I'm having trouble getting the syntax correct and am getting "Error in element 'set-variable' on line 25, column 18: Usage of member '' of type 'System.Object' is not supported within expressions".  Can anyone provide me with a way to do this?  Is it possible or is it not possible because I'm using a JArray (Object)?
I've read that there are only certain variable types available in the policies but it seems objects can be used within the C# code block (or is this not correct)?
Any tips appreciated, thanks in advance

If you want to get the id for the code == "PER" from your JSON array response, here is the code:
<set-variable name="emailId" value="@{
    var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(context.Response.Body.As<string>());
    var id = jsonArray.FirstOrDefault(x => x["code"].ToString() == "PER")?["id"].ToString();
    return id;
}" />


Thank you @10p, this works.  I actually have the comparison string coming in as a context variable.  Is it possible to swap out the "PER" for context.Variables["emailCode"].ToString()
When I try this I get
Usage of member '' of type 'System.Object' is not supported within expressions
thank you

You can use context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("emailCode")
